Movie about Cyborg/Robot lover with a woman
I'm looking for an English movie from 1990 - 2000s.
This movie started (in my memory) with a man and woman having sex naked (standing?) and suddenly they exploded after being too hot. It is in a company which makes cyborgs.
The main actress came to talk to the boss of this company and just to find that she had already met the "perfect man" (which looks 100% like just a normal man)while waiting and the boss told her you have already met him, the robot lover that is tailored for you.
The movie goes on with this couple happily in love and yet the robot started to be jealous and obsessed towards his "owner"/lover. I think she was under hostage and he started to get angry sensing that she is afraid of him. finally she had to destroy him but before he "dies" he still loves her and ask her to save him.

Aside from the cyborgs exploding after sex, it sounds like "The Companion" from 1994.

Oh my! It is!!! I cannot believe that someone out there can answer this. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!! and you are right about the exploding cyborg I have have seen another film and got it mixed up!

I am new to this web site. Is there a way that I can acknowledge that you have found a film for me? millions of thanks!

No, if I had put submitted it as an answer rather than a comment, then you could have voted it up and accepted it.  I was not 100% sure on the answer,  that is why I answered it in a comment.  No worries :)

The movie you are describing is the 1994 made-for-TV movie titled The Companion starring Bruce Greenwood.

In the near-distant future, a female romance writer is planning to
  write her next book in a remote mountain cabin. A friend convinces her
  to bring along a "companion", a nearly-human android to cook and
  clean. She settles on a male companion named "Geoffrey." Bored with
  some of Geoffrey's behavior, she tinkers with his programming -- first
  his personality, then his sexuality. Real trouble comes when she gives
  his mind access to "random data."

You can see the full movie online below - Warning, some NSFW content.



